# How to loop bootstrap Carousels? Empty fields after the last slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, loops, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

How to repair a bootstrap carousel? I have 6 elements on my slider. After the last item, the first empty fields are not loaded. When the last item on the screen is left, then all four are loaded. How to make the first item load immediately after the last item?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 active">
          <a href="Url 1">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 1" alt="slide 1">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
          <a href="Url 2">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 2" alt="slide 2">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
          <a href="Url 3">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 3" alt="slide 3">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
          <a href="Url 4">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 4" alt="slide 4">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
          <a href="Url 5">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 5" alt="slide 5">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
          <a href="Url 6">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block w-100" src="Url 6" alt="slide 6">
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The code I have in js is:

```
(function($) {
    $('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
var idx = $e.index();
var itemsPerSlide = 4;
var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction=="left") {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
        else {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
    }
}
});
})(jQuery);
```

Please help.

SOLVED :)
Code js:

```
(function($) {
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
var $t = $(this);
var $inner = $t.find('.carousel-inner');
var idx = $e.index();
var itemsPerSlide = 4;
var totalItems = $t.find('.carousel-item').length;

if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction=="left") {
            $t.find('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo($inner);
        }
        else {
            $t.find('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo($inner);
        }
    }
 }
});
})(jQuery);
```